# GWT: error running a GWT program from github

Tags: gwt

I am trying to run a project from [Github](https://github.com/stefanroeck/requestfactory/tree/master/tutorial)

I do not have much experience with Github , steps i am following is download program as zip , in that there's a folder name "tutorial", I import it to Eclipse ,try to run but it as Web Application but it says "select the war directory "

```
             It couldn't find the War Directory
```

I also tried to run it as "Run on server " but then it just give me the Html Page , but the application in not running

I am sure there's nothing wrong with the project asevery one else is running it well , There must be some thing i am doing wrong

Kindly Guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you compile the project first? Right Click > Google > GWT Compile. And then try Run As > Web Application. By default a GWT application's war directory is just in /war related to the project and some tutorial application should not have changed it.

If it is something else go to your run configurations in eclipse for the project and edit it to whatever it is. (war folder is were WEB-INF, etc is).